# 'error' event fires on my Backbone model no matter the http status code

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I am trying to create a base `Backbone` model that handles all my http errors.  Here is the code for the model:

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var Backbone = require('backbone');

  var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
      options || (options = {});
      this.bind("error", this.defaultErrorHandler);
      this.init && this.init(attributes, options);
    },

    defaultErrorHandler: function(model, error) {
      if(error.status === 401 || error.status === 403 || error.status === 500) {
        console.log(error.status);
      }
    }
  });
  return BaseModel;
});
```

Apparently the `error` event fires no matter what happens with the `http` call.  Even if I get  a `200` back from the server I still hit my `defaultErrorHandler`.  Could someone please explain what the `error` event that I have attached to really does?  Also, is there some kind of event that I can subscribe to that will only give me true errors?

Comment: The [events catalog](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) suggests it should only fire when a save call fails. I don't know backbone, but lots of these things return failure codes on HTTP 200 responses (there's a whole debate out there about whether to return 200 or one of the HTTP failure codes). Perhaps save is failing for a server-side reason, and returning an error on a 200 response?

Comment: I have access to the server and everything is working like it is supposed to.  I believe that this is some kind of misunderstanding on what the `error` event does.

Comment: backbone internally call jquery's ajax, and error event will called when there is no specific error handling when fetch function called. I suggest that you can write a test method, just use jquery's $.ajax to call your server to see if that work.

Comment: @jhamm: *"I believe that this is some kind of misunderstanding on what the error event does"* Dunno, what little that link says is pretty clear that it's only called on failure. Good luck,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you are right, it is really clear and that wasn't my smartest statement.  I looked in the `Backbone` docs and it says `"error" (model, xhr, options) — when a model's save call fails on the server`.  If my client is getting back a `200`, how does it know if the save failed or not?

Comment: @jhamm: I don't know backbone. But it's quite common for ajax-based things like that to return HTTP status code 200 but with information in the response saying the operation failed (not at the HTTP level, obviously, but at the application level). It's very common indeed. There's a big debate about whether to use 200 when returning a successful HTTP request that represents an application-level error, or to return one of the 4xx or 5xx codes. Both approaches have ardent fans and ardent critics. :-) So I'd use the network tab to look at what's coming back, see if there's a flag in there.

Comment: On `save` is your server responding with the saved model rendered as a JSON object? It might be helpful to post your `save` code and your server code. The Backbone `save` will try to sync the saved model with the response it gets from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone's save method will fail if: it does not get a 200 response from the server; the model has a method named `validate` that returns false. Although the docs don't say this explicitly, if you're saving a new record, I think it expects to get back a hash of attributes including an "id" attribute, which should be an integer. If it's missing, Backbone may assume that the record could not be saved server-side.